# BibLaTeX ext-authoryear "editor should be moved before the booktitle"

Tags: biblatex

I need to change the standard `ext-authoryear` format for book sections to:

> Doe, Jane (2021) 'Title'. In: Doe, John (ed.) *Book title*. Publisher.

My current output is:

[image: Screenshot of current layout]

In the [`biblatex-ext` bundle manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf) it is mentioned and on page 11 it is described that it is possible to print the name of the editor before the book title using the option `innamebeforetitle=true`. For some reason, this option does not seem to have any effect. What am I missing?

This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@inbook{Doe,
author = {Smith, Jane},
title = {Title},
editor = {Doe, John},
booktitle = {Book title},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,%
    style=ext-authoryear,%
    innamebeforetitle=true,%
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{references}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply use `@incollection` in place of `@inbook`

Comment: This nicely moves the editor behind the book title, but it also removes everything behind the editor, such as the publisher and pages. From the manual: "Whether or not the editor should be moved before the booktitle field for `@inbook`, `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` entries.". I would expect that it also works for `@inbook`.

Comment: The mention of `@inbook` in the manual is an oversight. I will fix that ASAP. As mentioned in https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/issues/20 so far all `@inbook`s that I have seen where you would want this behaviour were actually `@incollection`s, so I think the current behaviour is sensible, but I'll gladly look at real world examples of entries that cannot be `@incollection`s and must be `@inbook`s.

Comment: I had accidentally added a second '@` in front of `@incollection`. This was the reason, why my `@incollection‘ entry failed.

Answer (score 1):

As [Ivan](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/231952/ivan) says [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/585001/biblatex-ext-authoryear-editor-should-be-moved-before-the-booktitle#comment1470382_585001), you probably want to use `@incollection` instead of `@inbook` here.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}

\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Doe,
  author    = {Smith, Jane},
  title     = {Title},
  editor    = {Doe, John},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2021},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Smith, Jane (2021). “Title”. In: Doe, John (ed.). Book title. Publisher.]

The mention of `@inbook` in the documentation was an oversight that has since been corrected (in commit [`c6b792d`](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/commit/c6b792dc2585fe36d9ea09da79e00c62f5216c9e)).

As explained in https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/issues/20 and now also in the `biblatex-ext` documentation, the name you'd expect to see before the `booktitle` in an `@inbook` entry is the `bookauthor`, since `@inbook` is really 'in a `@book`', where the primary name is the author. For `@incollection` the name before the `booktitle` is the editor since `@incollection` is 'in a `@collection`' and the primary name associated with a `@collection` is its editor.

I have yet to see an example of an entry where it is desirable to print the `editor` before the `booktitle` that should needs to be an `@inbook` and could not be an `@incollection` . If you have an example of such an entry, please drop by https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/issues/20.